# Use partials on eco engine template

Tags: javascript, node.js, towerjs, eco

I'm trying something like this:

```
< %- @partial "includes/header" % >
```

But nothing is printed.

I'm using Tower.js. I tested it without Tower and works fine. EJS and some others template engines had the same problem. Just Coffekup worked fine with Tower.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using Express 3.x by any chance?

Comment: I'm using Tower.js. I tested without Tower and works fine. EJS and some others template engines had the same problem. Just Coffekup worked fine with Tower.